# Excluding specific set of files from lint issue report

Tags: go, sonarqube, lint

I am using gometalinterv2 in my Go project for linting. After the lint report is generated, the report file is linked to sonarqube for analysis and presentation.

I want to exclude some files like *_test.go from linting. I know there is a --exclude flag for gometalinterv2 to exclude folders. But since _test.go files are in the same folder/package as the source code, this won't work.

So is there any way to achieve this (either at linting stage or in sonar properties file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add config file `.gometalinter.json` to the root of your project and specify rules for excluding:

```
{
    "exclude": [
        ".*_test.go",
        "/any/folder/"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this "\*_.test.go"  be  ".\*_test.go". It worked, so thanks!

Comment: I meant, there should be dot before the asterisk. Otherwise gometalinterv2 command is throwing a regex error.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way after I marked @bayrinet's answer. The files (not just folders) to be excluded can also be passed to the command using the exclude flag like below -

```
>gometalinter.v2 ./... --exclude=somefolder --exclude=.*_test.go
```